# Office 365 Outlook is not showing Events and Meetings in Calender with Mac (Macmini, Macbook Air-2017, MacBookProM2)

Tags: macos, events, office365, meeting-request

There

I am having problems so many times with mac Os and office 365 Outlook. Below are the scenarios

- I licensed an office 365 account
- Using Mac OS - Macmini-2014 Version with Monterey OS, Macbook Pro M2(recently purchased with OS 13-Ventura)
- We are having our own email domain. WHM-Cpanel (But with the same domain events and meetings syncing with Windows OS-installed same Outlook-365)
- Configuring POP in outlook-365
- After configuring Unable to create new Events.
- If someone sends me a meeting/event invitation, getting an error or am not able to add that to the calendar. (* Attaching SS)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYAiP.png)

Tried almost everything, but now I am stuck.